# Swift filter function causes compile error

Tags: macos, swift

I have created a wrapper class for storing a weak object reference, and then. I want to remove objects that have not a valid reference inside.

```
class Weak<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var value : T?
    init (value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

protocol CSLocationServicesDelegate : class{

}


class conformance : CSLocationServicesDelegate{

}


class Dispatcher{
    var dispatchArray = Array<Weak<CSLocationServicesDelegate>>()

    func add( delegate : CSLocationServicesDelegate!){
        dispatchArray.append(Weak(value: delegate));
    }
    func remove(obj : CSLocationServicesDelegate!){
        dispatchArray.filter { (weakRef : Weak<CSLocationServicesDelegate>) -> Bool in
            return weakRef.value != nil; //change this line to "return true" and it works!!!

        }
    }
}
```

However Xcode compilation fails with an error being reported, which shows absolutely no specific error. I suspect that I am using the language in such a false manner, that Xcode cannot figure out what I want to do. If I change the line (in the comments) to what the comment says, it works.

Can anyone help me in achieving what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, but the compiler is crashing when compiling it. That should definitely be [reported to Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com).

One workaround for this seems to be to simply declare `Weak` as a `struct` instead of a `class`. This compiles just fine:

```
struct Weak<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var value : T?
    init (value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

protocol CSLocationServicesDelegate : class{

}


class conformance : CSLocationServicesDelegate{

}


class Dispatcher{
    var dispatchArray = Array<Weak<CSLocationServicesDelegate>>()

    func add( delegate : CSLocationServicesDelegate!){
        dispatchArray.append(Weak(value: delegate));
    }
    func remove(obj : CSLocationServicesDelegate!){
        dispatchArray.filter { (weakRef : Weak<CSLocationServicesDelegate>) -> Bool in
            return weakRef.value != nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent find. You saved me.